# Any way to work ctx.filter work on Safari?

Tags: canvas

I use `ctx.filter = 'blur(30px)';` this works on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, but Safari ignores this filter.

Any way to make it work ? some webkit workaround ?

Comment: https://github.com/flozz/StackBlur

Comment: I dont think this will work. I'll show some sample code: 

`function draw(e) {
    ...
    compositeOperation(compOper.lighter);
    ctx.filter = 'blur(15px)';
    stroke(grad, 5);
    ctx.filter = 'blur(30px)';
    stroke(hsl(0, 0, 100, 0.8), 2);
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found a solution!

Using this lib : https://github.com/davidenke/context-filter-polyfill, I make it work on Safari and improve performance on Firefox!

Comment: Sadly, this does currently not work together with `globalCompositeOperation`.

Comment: for the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/context-filter-polyfill) run ```npm i context-filter-polyfill``` and add ```import 'context-filter-polyfill/dist/index.js'``` to your js file