# canvas context filter blur not working in ios safari/chrome

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, css-filters

I want to draw some colors on person's image using canvas. And then blur the colors. To achieve this I am using canvas blur filter as following:

```
ctx.filter = 'blur('+ (box_width / 5) + 'px)';
```

But this blur filter is not supported in ios safari/chrome. Is there any alternative to achieve blur effect on a canvas/image that has cross browser compatibility?

this is how the image should look:

[image]

and in safari it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to work ctx.filter work on Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734486/any-way-to-work-ctx-filter-work-on-safari)

Comment: @Kaiido I have tried this plugin, it doesn't seem to work and breaks the images on iphone.

Comment: The questions are still the same. An other plugin you may want to try is [StackBlur.js](https://github.com/flozz/StackBlur)